# CENTOS LINUX cannot access example.com without hostname or www

Tags: linux, server, dns, centos, forwarding

I've configure a DNS Server on ROCKY linux. But It does not work like what I wanted.
I can ping to hostname.example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
But what I want is, I want to ping to example.com without hostname and www.

Can you guy help me pls !!!

Here is my configuration

[I've edit /etc/named.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHOZn.png)
zone "example.com" IN {
type master';'
file "example.com";
allow-update {none;}; };

[And I did create and edit file example.com in /var/named/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZrkY.png)
@   IN   SOA   example.com   root (
0
1H
1H
1H
1H )
IN  NS  localhost
server  IN  A   192.168.0.254
www     IN  A   192.168.0.254

Comment: Try [sf] or [unix.se] - this is not a programming problem and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you need to add

```
@ IN A 192.168.0.254
```

If this doesn't work, try '.' instead of '@'

Comment: Wow !!! it works with @. Thank you so much. You saved my life. Now I can continue do my homework. ✌

Comment: One more thing. If I want to ping to example only without .com. So I need to create a new zone ?

Comment: You mean as TLD? Yes.